# CI/CD for multi-project Git repo

Tags: git, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci

I have a main Git repo which maps few sub-projects and Git submodules.
Each one of those sub-projects is served from my main git project, which contains a docker-compose with a container for each sub-project.

Example:

```
Main 
| docker-compose.yml
| projects
  | Sub-project A (git submodule)
  | Sub-project B (git submodule)
  | Sub-project C (git submodule)
```

The actual code is stored in each sub-project, that as described, mapped as a git submodule.

I want my CI/CD (building containers, testing and deploying) to run in case that one of those sub-modules has changed.
For example, in case that I added new features to Sub-project A, I want to rebuild its docker image and deploy it to the server.

What will be the best practice for that? Is there an option to trigger the CI/CD by a change of sub-module? Does the trigger suppose to come from this Project CI/CD or the submodules?

Following the question below-

I am using Gitlab-ci, the projects written in some different languages (the docker containers adjust for each project).

As the main project purpose is to serve those submodules it is mandatory to include them in the process.

Comment: What language is your source code? What packaging solution can you use? What CI/CD solution do you use? Is the use of submodules mandatory in your use case? Can you have multiple Git repos instead of a single one?

Comment: @Tim I updated the question with the info

Comment: The best practice implies **not** using submodules. Unless very specific cases, it is always a failure in dependency management. The best practice is to have one repo per project (Git is not SVN), release each project using semver and package/deploy. Each Git repository triggers its own CI/CD pipelines. This is why I asked.