# CI/CD Pull Request approval after testing in multi repo microservices

Tags: kubernetes, testing, microservices, devops, git-submodules

I'm working on a personal project that I developed for learning purposes and I'm struggling on how to manage the following use case, similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58970917/ci-cd-for-multi-project-git-repo) or [this other one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64960431/pull-request-and-merge-actions-in-ci-cd).

I have a git repo that hosts **N** submodules, each of which contains **M** microservices, divided in directories. So, each submodule is a standalone git repository.

For the sake of semplicity, let me represent the tree structure:

```
my-project/
├─ .github/
│  ├─ workflows/
│  │  ├─ build_and_deploy.yml
│  │  ├─ another_new_action.yml *see >>>UPDATE
├─ submodule-1/
│  ├─ service-A/
│  │  ├─ .github/
│  │  │  ├─ workflows/
│  │  │  │  ├─ sync_to_parent.yml
│  │  ├─ app/
│  │  ├─ test/
│  │  ├─ kube/
│  │  ├─ Dockerfile
│  ├─ service-B/
│  │  ├─ ...
│  ├─ .gitignore
│  ├─ CODEOWNERS
│  ├─ namespace.yaml
├─ submodule-2/
│  ├─ service-C/
│  │  ├─ ...
│  ├─ .gitignore
│  ├─ CODEOWNERS
│  ├─ namespace.yaml
├─ .gitignore
├─ .gitmodules
├─ kustomization.yaml
├─ README.md
```

This parent repo (`my-project/`) is in sync with submodules whenever their main branches are updated: a dev pushes a new version of `service-A` to her branch, creates a Pull Request (**PR**) -> a codeowner approve the PR and merge to `main` of `service-A` -> GitHub Actions in the service (`sync_to_parent.yml`) will tell the parent repo the new commit hash for `main` branch. At last parent repo knows who has new incoming version and perform the deploy to production (`build_and_deploy.yml`).

How can I insert testing phase in the CI/CD pipeline if want parent repo will be the only one that builds and deploys to production?

I need this 'cause I'm using *k8s* to manage all (each submodule is a **namespace**). Tests are currently performed only locally, in *minikube*, and each service could depend on other ones.

I would like codeowner can accept the PR after the `service-A` passed the tests, but it should be the parent repo to fire action that builds minikube and tests `service-A` with its dependencies, and it will not know the new incoming versions of its submodules if sync does not happen (so, if PR is not accepted and merged to main).

A possible solution I came up with is to have this pipeline for testing and a second one on another parent repo copy that performs deploy:

1. A dev pushes a new version of `service-A` to her branch of `submodule-1`, then creates a Pull Request (**PR**)
2. A codeowner approve the PR and merge to `main` of `submodule-1`
3. `sync_to_parent.yml` will tell the parent repo the new commit hash for `main` branch
4. Parent repo performs tests on incoming new version: if there are FAILURES actors are notified, repos keep their dirty state, go back to **1**; if all tests PASSED, go to **5**
5. Parent repo peforms its copy to prod repository
6. Parent repo copy performs the deploy to production (`build_and_deploy.yml`)

I know that are some issues in this workaround...some questions are I'm thinking about like 'do I really need copy all parent repo and also all its children repos? can it be done with only branches?' or 'is it all safe?'.

Can it be a valid idea, what advantages and drawbacks could there be?

Is there any other way to manage this flow?

Hope all is well explained, thanks in advance!

***>>> UPDATE***

Can the following be another solution?

1. A dev pushes a new version of `service-A` to her branch of `submodule-1`, creates a PR for `new-feature-branch` this time (not for `main`, that will be forbidden)
2. A codeowner approve the PR and merge to `new-feature-branch` of `submodule-1`
3. `sync_to_parent.yml` will tell the parent repo `testing-branch` the new commit hash for `new-feature-branch` of `submodule-1`
4. Parent repo performs tests on incoming new version, collecting all needed dependencies: if there are FAILURES, actors are notified, parent repo `testing-branch` and `submodule-1` repo `new-feature-branch` keep their dirty state, go back to **1**; if all tests PASSED, go to **5**
5. Parent repo creates PR in `submodule-1` repo, from `new-feature-branch` to `main` (`another_new_action.yml`)
6. A codeowner eventually approve the PR or let `another_new_action.yml` do the merge directly
7. `sync_to_parent.yml` will tell the parent repo `main` the new commit hash for `main` branch of `submodule-1`
8. Parent repo can now perform the deploy to production (`build_and_deploy.yml`)